# array item index from an offset number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var list = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
```

Now I can obviously access the first, second and third element by their indexes, respectively 0 1 and 2. If I try to access `list[4]` I will get an error.

Is there a way so that, if I try to access the nth element outside of the array, the count starts form the beginning? so that `list[4]` would return "first"?

Keeping in mind that the number could also be bigger multiple times the length of the array itself.

Comment: Why would this ever happen?

Comment: (Moved link to wikipedia article to comment) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Accessing non-existent array elements will not throw any error, but return `undefined`

   ```
   var list = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
   console.log(list[3]);
   // undefined
   console.log(list[4]);
   // undefined
   ```
2. To wrap around the array, when the index is greater than the length, then you can use the mod operator, like this

   ```
   console.log(list[3 % list.length]);
   // first
   console.log(list[4 % list.length]);
   // second
   ```

Comment: Dang it! I was faster but this is more dynamic.  Yes... use the length of the list in your modulus operation.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote an example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/h8V9N/

```
Array.prototype.at = function(index) {  
     return index >= this.length ? this[0] : this[index]; 
};

// usage

var list = ['first', 'second', 'third']; 
console.log( list.at(88) );
```

i'm adding new method 'at' to Array object prototype.