# Given a JavaScript array, how to loop through and find a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array like so:

```
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];
```

Given a number from `0` to `Infinity`, how can I find a color value like so:

```
colors[0] === 'blue';
colors[1] === 'red';
colors[2] === 'green';
colors[3] === 'blue';
colors[4] === 'red';
colors[5] === 'green';
// …
```

After the array is exhausted, finding colors based on a numerical value should loop through the array in order.

Comment: Are you looking for some function to find the appropriate color based on the number, or are you looking for a way to make the _index accessors_ of the array behave as described? This is certainly possible using Proxies, like this: `const colors = new Proxy(["blue", "red", "green"], { get: (target, prop) => target[prop % target.length] });`. It’s unclear where looping through the array comes into play here, though. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array item index from an offset number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716843/array-item-index-from-an-offset-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any number "x" between 0 and infinity:

```
colors[x % colors.length]
```

Will get you one of your colours

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a fairly easy task to accomplish, all you have to do is to use **modulo** `%` operator when looking for a given index, as follows:

```
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'pink', 'black', 'white', 'anyother'];
function getColor(idx){
    return colors[idx % colors.length]
}

getColor(0) // "blue"
getColor(7) // "blue"
getColor(8) // "red"
getColor(13) // "anyother"
getColor(14) // "blue"
getColor(21) // "blue"
```

This way your array will stay intact and you won't get index higher than your array length.

Answer (score 0):

Use the remainder (%) operator. This will give you the remainder of a division.

1/3 = 0 Remainder 3

1%3 = 3

12/3 = 4 Remainder 0

12%3 = 0

```
if num % 3 == 0
    color = 'blue';
if num % 3 == 1
    color = 'red';
if num % 3 == 2
    color = 'green';
```

Comment: The `if` syntax is wrong, but even then, no one should use this repetative code.

Comment: It is called _pseudo_ code, and if that is truly the case, it should be _clearly marked_ as such.